# Regex *or other method* to sort through entire URL that's all text

Tags: java, regex, url, sorting, text

This link: http://www.otc.edu/GEN/schedule/all_classes_fall.txt contains classes for my college, and I am trying to take all of this data and store it in a ClassInformationFall object I have created. Basically, the classes begin at the class title in the format like this : "ABR-100-101" and have class instructor, days it occurs, start/end time, etc.

I have written some regex to pick out the class title, and some of the easier things like start and ending time, but I have been struggling on trying to get the rest of it out. I was thinking about setting up some code where anytime another class title is encountered, it adds the following text to a new ClassInformationFall object, which I am storing in a list of that type. Even if I had that, though, I still haven't been able to successfully extract all of the data for all of the things that make up the class.

What would be the regex to pick this information out, or is regex even the way to go?

Thanks for any help, this has stumped me for awhile.

PS - I am developing the application using this in Java.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without seeing some example text data.  I would probably process the file line by line (looking for certain strings) rather than use a regex... but it's hard to say without seeing the file.  Presumeably each piece of information is preceeded by a certain string that you need to search for.  If this is the case, a regex probably won't do anything to help.

Comment: @jahroy - follow the link and you'll see the file.  The data I saw appears to be better suited for awk or perl processing.

Comment: @jahroy Yes I provided a link. In any event, I am bound to dealing with it in java.

Comment: Ah... got it.  If the fields are always in the same order, I would just split the text by whitespace and process the elements of the resulting array.

Comment: @jahroy That's a good idea, and I hadn't thought of that. How can I split all the text by whitespace? I could take care of the rest.

Comment: Just created a very simple example as an answer...

Comment: Splitting by whitespace would improperly break things like `COLLEGE ACCOUNTING, PART I` but by tabs would be ok (if the fields are separated by tabs) or most look like fixed-width fields.

Comment: @StephenP -  Yep... Quickly realized that and used tabs in my example (which is how they're separated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are always in the same order, you can just split each line by tabs and deal with the resulting array.

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

while (line != null) {

   String[] data         =  line.split("\\t+");
   String   name         =  data[0];
   String   credits      =  data[2];
   String   description  =  data[3];
   String   professor    =  data[11];

   ClassInfo ci = new ClassInfo(name, credits, description, professor);
   classInfoList.add(ci);

   line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```